# How to split an array into a group of n elements each?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, .net-4.0

What is the best way to group an array into a list of array of n elements each in c# 4.

E.g

```
string[] testArray = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8" };
```

should be split into if we take n=3.

```
string[] A1 = {"s1", "s2", "s3"};
string[] A2 = {"s4", "s5", "s6"};
string[] A3 = {"s7", "s8"};
```

May be a simple way using LINQ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will generate an array of string arrays having 3 elements:

```
int i = 0;
var query = from s in testArray
            let num = i++
            group s by num / 3 into g
            select g.ToArray();
var results = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: +1, The only downside of this approach is that it's eagerly evaluated.  The entire query must be processed before a single element can be returned.

Comment: @JaredPar: Point well taken; however, depending on the size of the collection, or the nature of the processing, lazy evaluation may be overrated. Even so, +1 to your solution for providing a valid lazy approach.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there's a great built-in method for this but you could write one like the following.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupInto<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source,
  int count) {

  using ( var e = source.GetEnumerator() ) {
    while ( e.MoveNext() ) { 
      yield return GroupIntoHelper(e, count);
    }
  }    
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GroupIntoHelper<T>(
  IEnumerator<T> e,
  int count) {

  do {
    yield return e.Current;
    count--;
  } while ( count > 0 && e.MoveNext());
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. But should provide an example of how it solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 8):

```
int size = 3;
var results = testArray.Select((x, i) => new { Key = i / size, Value = x })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value, (k, g) => g.ToArray())
                       .ToArray();
```

If you don't mind the results being typed as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` rather than `T[][]` then you can omit the `ToArray` calls altogether:

```
int size = 3;
var results = testArray.Select((x, i) => new { Key = i / size, Value = x })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is actually arrays that you are working with rather than general IEnumerables, and especially if the arrays are very large, then this method is a very fast and memory effecient way to do it. If you really just want a LINQ statement, then nevermind.

```
    private static T[][] SliceArray<T>(T[] source, int maxResultElements)
    {
        int numberOfArrays = source.Length / maxResultElements;
        if (maxResultElements * numberOfArrays < source.Length)
            numberOfArrays++;
        T[][] target = new T[numberOfArrays][];
        for (int index = 0; index < numberOfArrays; index++)
        {
            int elementsInThisArray = Math.Min(maxResultElements, source.Length - index * maxResultElements);
            target[index] = new T[elementsInThisArray];
            Array.Copy(source, index * maxResultElements, target[index], 0, elementsInThisArray);
        }
        return target;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 6+, the [Chunk extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0) method was added, its really well summarized by this article here: https://exceptionnotfound.net/bite-size-dotnet-6-chunk-in-linq/

```
string[] testArray = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8" };
testArray.Chunk(3);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

[MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) provides `Batch` extension method

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Extension

```
public static class Extension
{
    private static IEnumerable<TList> Split<TList, T>(this TList value, int countOfEachPart) where TList : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        int cnt = value.Count() / countOfEachPart;
        List<IEnumerable<T>> result = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= cnt; i++)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> newPart = value.Skip(i * countOfEachPart).Take(countOfEachPart).ToArray();
            if (newPart.Any())
                result.Add(newPart);
            else
                break;
        }

        return result.Cast<TList>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>> Split<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> value, int countOfEachPart)
    {
        IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> result = value.ToArray()
                                                            .Split(countOfEachPart)
                                                            .Select(p => p.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value));
        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Split<T>(this IList<T> value, int countOfEachPart)
    {
        return value.Split<IList<T>, T>(countOfEachPart);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T[]> Split<T>(this T[] value, int countOfEachPart)
    {
        return value.Split<T[], T>(countOfEachPart);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, int countOfEachPart)
    {
        return value.Split<IEnumerable<T>, T>(countOfEachPart);
    }
}
```