# split SortedList to multiple lists or arrays

Tags: c#, .net, sortedlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split an array into a group of n elements each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514740/how-to-split-an-array-into-a-group-of-n-elements-each)

I believe I oversimplified this question so I am editing it a bit. From within a .NET 3.5 console application I have a SortedList string,string that will contain an unknown number of key/value pairs. I will get this collection by reading in rows from a table within a Microsoft Word document. The user will then be able to add additional items into this collection. Once the user has finished adding to the collection I then need to write the collection back to a new Microsoft Word document. The difficulty is that the items must be written back to the document in alphabetical order to a multicolumn table, first down the left side of the table and then down the right side of the table and since the output will likely be spread across multiple pages I need to also keep the order across multiple pages. So the first table on the first page may contain A through C on the left side of the table and C through F on the right side of the table then if the table exceeds the page a new table is needed. The new table may contain F through I and the right side L through O.Since the table will likely span multiple pages and I know the maximum number of rows per table per page I can do the math to determine how many tables I will need overall. This image is representative of the output:
[image: table output]
For the sake of brevity if a output table can contain a maximum of 7 rows per page and 2 items per row and I have 28 items then I will need to write the output to 2 tables but of course I won't really know how many tables I will need until I read in the data so I can't simply hardcode the number of output tables.

What is the best way to take my SortedList and split it out into n collections in order to create the table structure described?

Comment: the post you pointed out did exactly what I needed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to split the list (if the only purpose is to write items in a table).

You can just iterate through the list and write row breaks in appropriate places.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count; i++)
{
   if (i % 3 == 0)
   {
       Console.Write("|"); // write beginning of the row
   }
   Console.Write(sortedList[i].ToString().PadRight(10)); // write cell
   Console.Write("|"); // write cell divider
   if (i % 3 == 2)
   {
      Console.WriteLine() // write end of the row       
   }
}
// optional: write empty cells if sortedList.Count % 3 != 0
// optional: write end of the row if sortedList.Count % 3 != 2
```

You should extend your question by specifying what is the output of your script. If you want to write a table to the console, the above solution is probably the best. However, if you are using rich user interface (such as WinForms or ASP.NET), you should use built-in tools and controls to display data in table.

Answer (score 0):

I played with LINQ a little bit and came up with this solution. It creates some kind of tree structure based on the "input parameters" (`rowsPerPage` and `columnsPerPage`). The columns on the last page could not have the same size (the code can be easily fixed if it is a problem).

```
SortedList<string, string> sortedList ... // input sortedList

int rowsPerPage = 7;
int columnsPerPage = 2;

var result = from col in
                 (from i in sortedList.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                 group i by (i.Index / rowsPerPage) into g
                 select new { ColumnNumber = g.Key, Items = g })
             group col by (col.ColumnNumber / columnsPerPage) into page
             select new { PageNumber = page.Key, Columns = page };

foreach (var page in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page no. {0}", page.PageNumber);
    foreach (var col in page.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tColumn no. {0}", col.ColumnNumber);
        foreach (var item in col.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tItem key: {0}, value: {1}", item.Item.Key, item.Item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```